# Where is the msdb database for standalone SSIS Servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, bids

I am working on a DWH application. The server I was granted access to only has SSIS installed with no database engine. I am getting errors like:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_listfolders', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

I need to verify the permissions on the database engine and on the msdb. Is there a way how to find which server is configured to host the msdb database?

Comment: What is the type of application? where packages are stored?

Comment: Tha packages are by default stored in MSDB which I failed to locate. What do you mean by application type?

Comment: From where your package are called, `.exe` file or anything else?

Comment: Scheduled task executing DTExec

Comment: can you show the scheduled command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it!

It is hidden in a configuration file in the installation folder of SSIS. Browse to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn` then look for the file called `MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml`. The server name is just sitting there, and can be changed as you wish.

[image: MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml]

Comment: This is helpful. Congratulations!!

Answer (score 2):

After reading your comments, You have to go to the windows scheduled task and read the command running the `Dtexec utility`

The command will look like the following:

```
C:\..\dtexec /SQL "\Package1" /SERVER "Test\Test" /USER "blabla" /PASSWORD "blabla"
```

The string after `/SERVER` keyword is the server name where the packages are located

if the package are not located in a SQL server and are executed from a package file the command will look like:

```
C:\..\dtexec /F "C:\Packages\Package1.dtsx"
```

Then  go to the package open it and read connection strings from it.

Read more about DtExec utility in these articles:

- [Dtexec Utility MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx)
- http://www.sqlshack.com/ways-use-execute-sql-server-integration-services-packages/

**Info about the exception Thrown**

In SQL server, The user account associated with the connection in the `Execute Package` needs to be granted the `db_ssisoperator` role in the msdb database, otherwise it can’t find the other package that is being called.

And it might needs also to add yourself to the roles below:

- `db_ddladmin`
- `db_ssisadmin`

You can find other suggestions in these links:

- https://pacheco.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/situation-an-s/
- http://dbdevs.blogspot.com/2015/02/granting-access-to-ssis-server.html
- http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/07/resolving-error-execute-permission.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1421866-1bd6-4978-a04c-75e2f8c7d69a/permission-issue-or-something-else?forum=sqlintegrationservices